# Passing parameters (with spaces) to batch file from java program

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

In my program i want to execute the jar with some parameters with the help of .bat file.

**.bat file**

```
%6 -jar %5 -u %1 -p %2 -dbbkp %3 > %4
```

**java Program that pass parameters to above .bat file**

```
String jarPath=request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"/OES-SmartClient/OES-SmartClient.jar";

String outputfilepath=request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"/resources/WebFiles/OESFiles/DBBackupStatus.txt";

 String jrePath="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java";

 String batfilePath = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"/WEB-INF/classes/OESDBBackup.bat";
        String BackupLocation = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"/WEB-INF/classes/BackupLocation";

        batfilePath="\""+batfilePath+"\"";
        jarPath="\""+jarPath+"\"";
        outputfilepath="\""+outputfilepath+"\"";
        BackupLocation="\""+BackupLocation+"\"";

    process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(batfilePath +" "+ dbUser.getUserName()+" "+ dbUser.getPassword()+" "+BackupLocation+" "+outputfilepath+" "+jarPath+" "+jrePath);
```

this above code is for taking database backup.

When i am running this programs its not giving the error but also its fail to take database backup.

when  i am giving BackupLocation like "C:\Sm\"(without space parameter) then its working properly.

Please anyone can suggest me how to pass my parameters with spaces.

Comment: Try to Run your batch file with [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

Comment: can i pass parameters as same as above to process builder?

Comment: You could pass the parameter like `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(batfilePath, dbUser.getUserName(), dbUser.getPassword(), BackupLocation, outputfilepath, jarPath, jrePath);`. For more information follow the link to the Javadoc proposed by @Vikas.

Comment: I have added following code but its not working..
process = new ProcessBuilder(filePath , dbUser.getUserName(), dbUser.getPassword(),BackupLocation,DBBackupStatusFilePath,smartClientPath,jrePath).start();